# MongoDB is posible to change the value in db (not update), before to get a find() result? Pymongo

Tags: python, database, find, pymongo

Having this collection:

```
{"_id":"5f96dbad2c127e4cdc6444eb","name":"FIRST NAME"}
{"_id":"5f96dbad2c127e4cdc6444eb","name":"SECOND NAME"}
```

I want to find where the value in database is in lowercase and without space. For example this find `{name:"firstname"}` will return none, and it won't return none if I change the value (not a update) to lowercase and remove space. Maybe it's better to make a transform before to insert in database, but I wanted to try this.

```py
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client.test_database
collection = db.test_collection
result = collection.find()
for i in result:
    i['name'] = i['name'].lower().replace(' ', '')
    if value_to_search == i['name']:
        return True
```

I would like to do not use a `for` loop, want to know how to do it in a mongo query (if it's posible to do)

Comment: Are you asking if MongoDB supports insert triggers?

Comment: Hmmm.... No, for example `find()` return all values in collection, right?
```
value_to_search="firstname"
for i in collection.find():
 i['name] = i['name'].lower().replace(' ', '')
 if(value_to_search == i['name] )
  return true;
```
So, what I would like to do, is not to use a for, want to know how to do it in a mongo query (if it's posible to do)

Comment: Have you considered using [$regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/)?

Comment: Not, but what you have in mind? Because, regex I don't see it. If pattern is `firstname` (my search value),  will return none because in db is `First Name`